# I want to check is the product label correct or slipped? Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am doing a project that checks whether the labels on the ketchup bottles are outside the boundaries we want or are they correct. I am using python and opencv.

My goal is to set a boundaries and check if the tag has exceeded those limits.

I want to add boundaries like this:

[image: I add on paint to show my goal]

I mean, for example, in the red area between the green rectangle and the edge of the ketchup bottle, I'm aiming to check if there is a pixel (so there is a slip on the label). --> [example areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZOb.png)

So far I have done blurring the image and then I found the edges with the canny edge.

Blurred image:

[image: blurred image]

After finding edges:

[image: after finding edges]

After this point, I want to add a frame to the picture where I found the edges and check if there are any pixels outside the border, but I'm stuck at this point.

I'm open to suggestions on how to do this.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('ketchup1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 75, 225)

cv2.imshow("blurred image", blur)
cv2.imshow("canny image", canny)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you add a border around the edges you have found, how can there possibly be any pixels outside the border?

Comment: I want to add a border as a rectangular area to check if there is a pixel that actually overflow that border. So actually, inside that border is our safe zone, our label is correct.

Comment: So adding the border is independent of finding the edges and the border is just a fixed area?

Comment: Yes exactly. Border is fixed and independent. Also I add a new photo to show my goal.

Comment: How would you know if there the edges you find outside belong to the label or to the bottle?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't know how to do this. I thought to check if there are pixels in the red rectangular area like in the photo I put in the post. I'm new to image processing, I'm open to suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Such inspections will always start with a global location of the object, because the bottles will not always be exactly placed. This can be done by template matching, or detection of the external edges (in an horizontal strip).

First solution:

Take a sample image and define a binary mask such as the one below. Then during inspection, after registering the mask on the image, count the edge pixels inside the mask area.

Second solution:

Use template matching to locate just the label and compare its position to that of the bottle.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, you're right bottles may will not always in the same place.